# how to perform fourier transform of following

Tags: fourier-transform

I wish to write the following integral in the frequency domain

$$\int_{-\infty}^{0}\int_{-\infty}^{0} d\tau_2 d\tau_1 f(\tau_1,\tau_2)g(\tau_1,\tau_2) + \int_{0}^{t}\int_{0}^{t} d\tau_2 d\tau_1 f(\tau_1,\tau_2)(g(\tau_1,\tau_2)+h(\tau_1,\tau_2))$$

I have additional information that the functions are time-independent hence
$$f(\tau_1,\tau_2) = f(\tau_1-\tau_2)$$ and similar for $g$ and $h$.

I want to represent these in the frequence domain. Since the integral limits are broken and not even completely going to $+\infty$, I am a bit confused towards how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$f(\tau_{1}, \tau_{2})g(\tau_{1}, \tau_{2})=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}\Big[\hat{f}(\omega_{1}, \omega_{2})*\hat{g}(\omega_{1}, \omega_{2})\Big]e^{i\omega_{1}\tau_{1}}e^{i\omega_{2}\tau_{2}}d\omega_{1}d\omega_{2}$$
So,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{0}f(\tau_{1}, \tau_{2})g(\tau_{1}, \tau_{2})d\tau_{1}d\tau_{2}=$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}\Big[\hat{f}(\omega_{1}, \omega_{2})*\hat{g}(\omega_{1}, \omega_{2})\Big]e^{i\omega_{1}\tau_{1}}e^{i\omega_{2}\tau_{2}}d\omega_{1}d\omega_{2}d\tau_{1}d\tau_{2}=$$
$$=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}\Big[\hat{f}(\omega_{1}, \omega_{2})*\hat{g}(\omega_{1}, \omega_{2})\Big]\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{i\omega_{1}\tau_{1}}e^{i\omega_{2}\tau_{2}}d\tau_{1}d\tau_{2}d\omega_{1}d\omega_{2}=$$
$$=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}\frac{\Big[\hat{f}(\omega_{1}, \omega_{2})*\hat{g}(\omega_{1}, \omega_{2})\Big]}{\omega_{1}\omega_{2}}d\omega_{1}d\omega_{2}$$
Can do the same with the other integral